# Цвет в библиотеке turtle

Tags: python, color, turtle, rgb

Как изобразить/интерпретировать цвет в формате (R, G, B) в библиотеке turtle?
Пробовал делать следующее:

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()

# Первый способ
window.bgcolor(12, 23, 45)

# Второй способ
window.bgcolor((12, 23, 45))
```

Во всех способах выводило ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по документации к [.bgcolor()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgcolor)
, в качестве параметра тут может быть одно из:

- a color string
- three numbers in the range 0..colormode
- 3-tuple of such numbers

  ```py
  >>> screen.bgcolor("orange")
  >>> screen.bgcolor()
  'orange'
  >>> screen.bgcolor("#800080")
  >>> screen.bgcolor()
  (128.0, 0.0, 128.0)
  ```

Comment: При этом у colormode два варианта: 1.0 и 255. https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode